# Non-metric distances

Tags: metric-spaces

Could anybody suggest practically important distances that are significantly non-metric and are not Bregman divergences? For instance, they are non-symmetric and not equivalent to the Euclidean distance.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing then you're also not interested in f-divergences or the alpha-divergences ? Also, I don't know if you're implying that Bregman divergences *are* equivalent to Euclidean distances, because they're not.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but aren't distances on any real road network non-symmetric? (due to one-way-roads and so on)

Comment: Hi Suresh, Bregman divergences are not equivalent, for sure. I only meant that we worked with Bregman divergences, but also wanted to try divergences of different types. Thank you for suggesting f- and -alpha divergences. Is the alpha-divergence the same as  Rényi divergence?

Comment: Shir, could you provide a reference? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe distance between nodes in directed graphs would interest you.

Comment: What Shir is talking about is probably the same as what MCH suggests: Shortest paths in directed graphs. For undirected graphs, shortest-path-distances yield metrics, but if the edges are directed, the resulting distance may (depending on the graph layout) be asymmetric. It will still obey the oriented triangle inequality, though; i.e., it's a quasimetric: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Quasimetrics

Comment: I think the Renyi divergences are a special class of $\alpha$-divergences.

Comment: Thank you for the information. The most interesting functions that non-symmetric and "non-triangular". Yet, distances in graphs can be interesting too.

Answer (score 6):

For a really thorough listing of various distances, metric or not, that are in use, I recommend [Encyclopedia of Distances](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642309577) by Deza and Deza. (It is also available electronically from Springer.) For a really simple example of a family of non-metric distances, you can simply let $p$ be less than 1 for an [$L_p$ distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space), for example. For a family that is in heavy, actual use, you could look into various forms of [weighted edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance). There's also the cosine measure, Jeffrey divergence, partial Hausdorff distance, dynamic time warping distance, and domain-dependent distances such as the COSIMIR model, all discussed in [Skopal's paper on indexing non-metric distances](http://siret.ms.mff.cuni.cz/skopal/pub/TODSpreprint.pdf).

Comment: Second the pointer to the Deza and Deza book. It's a very nice reference.

Comment: Cool, excellent paper, I have also found a more recent survey by Bustos & Skopal (On nonmetric similarity search problems in complex domains). Do I get it correctly that TriGen is designed for symmetric distances, or, is there a non-symmetric extension?

Comment: He discusses how to circumvent the asymmetry, as far as I can recall (e.g., by using $d'(x,y) = d(x,y) + d(y,x)$ or the like).

Comment: @LeonidBoytsov you might also be aware of the Jensen-Shannon type approaches to symmetrizing the Bregman divergences.

Comment: Yes, symmetrization is an option.